# Build interactive dashboard using dash python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

so i am trying to make a interactive dashboard using dash plotly in python using below data as example:

```
        Date  Traded Qty  Deliverable Qty  Delivery %     LTP  Open Interest
0 2020-12-18    29816205          5872798       19.70  268.15       73110000
1 2020-12-21    55160758         14528986       26.34  272.00       71454000
2 2020-12-22    51189571         10781372       21.06  253.85       71013000
3 2020-12-23    29056404          4792004       16.49  258.20       67350000
4 2020-12-24    28585509          6820426       23.86  263.75       68697000
```

It is saved as pandas dataframe and want to it be similar to below image:

[image: chart]

Sorry for my shitty drawing.
In chart I want "Delivery %" to be show when hover over "Deliverable Qty"

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Which elements do you want to make interactive in Dash?

Comment: @r-beginners i want to make dashboard like above image in dash using the dataframe given as example

Comment: You can certainly do that, but this is far beyond the scope of a single SO question. I would probably start with two plotly charts, a stacked bar chart and a line chart. Check out [the docs](https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing) for some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with Dash, but [this page](https://dash.plotly.com/layout) will help you do it. I suggest you look into it and try to write some code before asking questions. I'm in a jupyterlab environment, so I've implemented some live riley for it.

```
import dash 
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash 
import dash_core_components as dcc 
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import io
import pandas as pd 

data = '''
Date  "Traded Qty"  "Deliverable Qty"  "Delivery %"     LTP  "Open Interest"
0 2020-12-18    29816205          5872798       19.70  268.15       73110000
1 2020-12-21    55160758         14528986       26.34  272.00       71454000
2 2020-12-22    51189571         10781372       21.06  253.85       71013000
3 2020-12-23    29056404          4792004       16.49  258.20       67350000
4 2020-12-24    28585509          6820426       23.86  263.75       68697000
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df['Date'], y=df['Traded Qty'], name='Traded Qty'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df['Date'],
                     y=df['Deliverable Qty'],
                     name='Deliverable Qty',
                     hovertext=df['Delivery %'],
                     hovertemplate='<br>'.join([
                         'Deliverable Qty: %{y}',
                         'Delivery %: %{hovertext}'
                     ])
                    ))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['LTP'], mode='lines+markers', name='LTP'), secondary_y=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['Open Interest'], mode='lines+markers', name='Open Interest'))

fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(type = "category"), barmode='stack', margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=20, b=20))
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0,300], secondary_y=True)

# instance create
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
# app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H3(children='Trade Chart'),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig
    )
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # notebook on action
    app.run_server(mode='inline')
    # app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]

Comment: if there is no data on holidays like you can see in chart dec19,dec20 was holiday and its blank. is there a way to ignore those days in bar chart and show only work days. and can you please resize the bars

Comment: `fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(type = "category"),...)`If you modify it in this way, the holiday will not be covered.